# How to pop the split view controller "DetailViewController?"

Tags: iphone

```
     detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    [self.splitViewController.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    detailViewController.strDetailId = [teaserSectionOneArray objectAtIndex:indexValue] ;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
    [viewControllerArray removeAllObjects];
    [viewControllerArray addObject:detailViewController];
    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO];
    [self.splitViewController.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [viewControllerArray release];
```

This code using for push to the detail view. How do I pop to another view controller in detail view when I click the button? Its not supported the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. How to handle this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do? What is not working?

Comment: I am pushing master view to detail view. In detail view not working the pop action. I want ordinary pop action for the button click, But not support the pop action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wooooow thats NOT how you push a view controller on the stack of a navigationController !!

You don't have to call `viewWillDisappear`, `viewWillAppear` and such yourself ! You don't have to add the `detailViewController` to the `splitViewController.viewControllers` array yourself either!

What you need to do is this:

- Make sure your UISplitViewController has a `NavigationController` as part of its `detailViewController` (namely the ViewController that is on the right of the screen should be an `UINavigationController`, not a regular `UIViewController`).
- The rest is then easy as it works the same way as any regular `UINavigationController`. The fact that your `UINavigationController` is the right part of an `UISplitViewController` is not different than when you use an `UINavigationController` in any other context.

Simply use `pushViewController:animated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:` methods of `UINavigationController` to push and pop your view controllers. Access your `UINavigationController` from your `UISplitViewController` using either a custom `IBOutlet` that you added to point to it, or by accessing `(UINavigationController*)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am pushing master view to detail view. I want to click the button in detail view then perform the pop action. Detail view not support pop action because I not using ordinary pushViewController:animated:. So search some solution. Please Give more idea

Comment: Embed your detailView into a NavigationController (whose rootViewController will be your detailView) and use standard push/pop methods, that is the most simple solution.